# How should I include aws-appsync in AngularJS project

Tags: angularjs, npm, gulp, bower, aws-appsync

I am working on a AngularJS project that uses bower as package manager and gulp to inject the dependencies into the index.html file.  I am not very familiar with both of these tools.

I now want to use AWS AppSync, but it is not available as a bower package.

Currently the AWS SDK is specified as a file dependency in `bower.json` as:

`"aws-sdk": "./thirdparty/script/aws-sdk-2.69.0.min.js",`

When I install aws-appsync with npm `npm install aws-appsync` the node_modules folder for aws-appsync contains multiple js files in the lib directory.

How can I include these with bower or is there another way to do this altogether?

I am currently unable to change much of the build and dependency management process so any suggestions working with the current tools would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I *hacked* together an interim solution until I can move the whole project over to npm and browserify.

I added the `aws-appsync` package using npm and `require`d it in a new file.  This file is then passed through a gulp task that uses the browserify plugin. The added file is then included into the rest of the build process as before.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out!

The Bower team itself [has recommended that people migrate to npm or yarn](https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/), and so aws-appsync has not been pushed to Bower.

It might be worth investigating whether you can install directly from github using something like...

```
bower install <github url>.git
```

... and install directly from the appsync-sdk github repo.

Comment: While bower adds the app-sync source, it's the typescript source. I do not wish to add another step to the gulp build process to compile that as well.  Is there a clean  way to both use packages from bower and npm with a gulp build process, to be able to steadily migrate over to npm only?